# Angular and Typescript Sending Post Request

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a simple page with angular and typescript with just 1 button and 1 text field. I want to make a post request to a link that posts the string written in text box.

my button html:

```
 <a class="button-size">
      Add Customer
    </a>
```

and button ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'customer-button123',
  templateUrl: './blabla',
  styleUrls: ['./clacla']
})
export class AddCustomerButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

text box html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Customer Name">
</mat-form-field>
```

text box ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'customer-text-field',
  templateUrl: './blabla2',
  styleUrls: ['./clacla2']
})
export class CustomerTextFieldComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and simple wrapper page html is:

```
<div class="input-label">
    <mg-customer-text-field></mg-customer-text-field>
</div>

<div>
  <mg-customer-button123></mg-customer-button123>
</div>
```

How can i send a post reques to link localhost8080/admin/addCustomer ?

Comment: I don't see any data binding...

Comment: can you help me narrow down your question? do you want help in getting the value of the <mg-customer-text-field></mg-customer-text-field> component or making a Post request with the dataload or both?

Comment: U created button in separate page and text form in separate page and r u trying to create in separate pages?

Comment: you might need a service to do this for you, your button should call a function defined on your .component.ts, than this component calls the function of you service, to create this function, check out the HttpClient examples, it's pretty straightfoward.

Answer (score 0):

If you hosting your front end at port: 4200 (default Angular port serve) and you want to send a request to http://localhost8080/admin/addCustomer, you will need a proxy configuration. You can see right here for more info: https://itnext.io/angular-cli-proxy-configuration-4311acec9d6f

Answer (score 0):

You use the [HttpModule](https://angular.io/api/http/HttpModule)

I use a service to separate http requests.

**Example**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'customer-button123',
  templateUrl: './blabla',
  styleUrls: ['./clacla']
})
export class AddCustomerButtonComponent implements OnInit {

data: any;
results: any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
    getDataFromApi() {
      this.apiService.getData(this.data).subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results;
    });
 }
```

**ApiService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getData(data): any {
  return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/get-data`);
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="input-label">
  <mg-customer-text-field [(ngModel)]="data"></mg-customer-text-field>
</div>

<div>
  <mg-customer-button123 (click)="getDataFromApi()"></mg-customer-button123>
</div>
```